# Accessing PC localhost from Mac over WiFi

Tags: mac, wifi, localhost, desktop, adhoc-network

I have a web service running on the localhost of my PC.  I set up an ad hoc local wifi network and I would like to access the web service from my Mac.  Can this be done?

What would the url to my web service be?  (http://localhost:49973/BaseballWebService/Service.asmx - insert static ip somewhere?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as easy as simply replacing the word 'localhost' with the IP or DNS address of your 'server' machine. That said you may have firewall rules, web server setup options etc. which could get in the way of this but it's worth trying first of all as it's so easy.

Comment: That didn't work.  How would I tell if a firewall was intercepting.  Can the IP be automatically assigned?

Answer (score 1):

From the mac browse to:

http://:49973/BaseballWebService/Service.asmx

That's the basics of it.

To find your PC's IP: Start -> Run. Then type in cmd. At the console type and run:

ipconfig /all

You'll have to find the IP address being used on the ad-hoc network. This might well be different to your normal IP, especially if you also have ethernet, etc.

Check your firewall on the PC too. Do you know which firewall you have running? Which OS are you running?

This is more of a PC than a Mac question.